# LESS: how to check value is integer like in javascript value%1 == 0

Tags: css, integer, less

How to tell in a LESS function/mixin that a number is integer similar to Javascript's usual function:

```
var data = 22;

if(data % 1 === 0){
  // yes it's an integer.
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I am trying to determine the right line-height for some buttons based on a global reference value, small buttons are usually reference/2 and this reference value can be sometimes 23, and 23/2 = 12.5 a value that's pretty much unusable if I cannot check it's remainder.

Comment: what about `@line_height: ceil(@reference / 2);`?

Comment: I need a sort of `if (reference/2_has_remainder)` check no matter what to set other LESS variables it's not just about rounding the value... your answer scored, so stay cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of [guarded namespaces](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-guarded-namespaces) and the [`floor`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#math-functions-floor) function.

Here is a [live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNVBBP) on codepen. Try changing the value of `@my_val` to something without a fractional part (this includes values like `1.0`) and watch the text turn green.

---

LESS:

```
@my_val: 55.6;

#my_text {
  color: red;
  /* if @my_val has no fractional part */
  & when (@my_val = floor(@my_val)) {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="my_text">Green if integer, red otherwise.</span>
```

Comment: Such a simple idea, thanks so much. I will test asap and come back with feedback and / or further improvements.